# What is the best proxy solution for my use case?

Tags: proxy, ip, cloud, vpn, vps

Hi for over 3 years I've been using free trials from cloud server to resolve this issue but lately the trial credit they provide isn't enough for more than two months of use and I'd rather set up a more permanent solution for my use case.

Currently:
I create a windows or ubuntu VPS instance to get a unique IP each time
I have at least 3-4 open at a time, preferably keep the same IP for as long as possible for each instance

I'm turning my old PC as a vps server, but I need a solution to give each instance its own IP

What should I go for (cheapest) to give each instance its own IP (preferably residential)? A private residential proxy? a private IP VPN? Should I layer my proxies (aka. Have a public vpn running on the main desktop and connect to the private proxies on the VMs)?

This whole proxy field has been always been confusing to me considering all the different types of proxies there are and I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you very much for reading and hopefully for answering as well!

Answer (score -1):

You can go free for 1 year with amazon aws, microsoft azure or google cloud vps, or you can purchase something like alicloud vps or https://www.hetzner.com/cloud (the cheapest)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, yes I've been doing that and I'd rather have a more permanent solution instead of hopping trials constantly. I used to have to change trials every 5 months and now it's every month or two, also takes too much of my time away to do so.

Comment: you can look here  https://www.hetzner.com/cloud if you need small server you will pay it only 3$/mouth or if you want something more powerfull you can get vps with good cpu here https://www.vultr.com/?ref=7887253

Comment: I'd rather look for a DIY scaleable solution even if it means saving 50 cents more per instance a month, I keep needing more and more.

Comment: You have to buy a server (not personal computer) install something like vmware server, register domain or dns and redirect to your ip, than you have to setup routing based on request url example.com/server1 -> server1, example.com/server2 ->server2 etc.... or the same with subdomains

Comment: A personal computer can be turned into a dedicated server, I'm not hosting from my servers, I'm using them for individualized browsing on their own IPs, nothing complex, there is no need to set up routing and so on. It's pretty simple.